# Chrome devtools extension inspect window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I use chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceContentCommitted.addListener event to get css changes on the inspect window.

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceContentCommitted.addListener(function(resource, content) {
    // some code
});
```

When I change css that has resource file it works perfect. but, when I change the document (html or css) it doesn't fire the event.

Do i miss something? Is it different event for the document?

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

[onResourceContentCommitted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#event-onResourceContentCommitted)

> Fired when a new revision of the resource is committed (e.g. user
>   saves an edited version of the resource in the Developer Tools)

So you need to save your changes to fire it

Comment: Hey, I do get Resource changes but I need document changes, like inline css or text inside a DIV. :)
Thanks.